# how to force a main tab to load when using navbar?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I am just learning the ropes of twitter bootstrap. This is newbie question so please bear wit me. I do not have any javascript in the code, all I am trying to do is learn the bootstrap classes. I am creating simple web page to to learn the tab controls. The main page when loads have the site name and couple of navigation options (please take look at my test website http://www.13favs.com/static ) On page load, it displays the menu bar properly. When you click first option in the menu, the content displays properly. now select the second option and it displays the content properly. If you would choose the main page name (left most menu title) now it display hero content which I wanted to display on page load. I have two part question

Is it possible to display the hero content on load as it would display the main page title or do we need to use javascript to force that as active tab to make it display?

I created a jsFiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/unni/8vBkC/ to test this one, but in this the content is not even displayed on selecting the menu option, even though I have both javascript and bootstrap js are enabled. Here the core code I am trying to test

```
<nav class=navbar navbar-inverse>
<div class="navbar-inner"> <a class="brand" href="#main">Main Page</a>

    <ul class="nav">
        <li><a href="#first" data-toggle="nav">First</a>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#second" data-toggle="nav">Second</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

First
    Second

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can display the hero content on load by adding the class `active` to the hero tab like this:

```
<div class="hero-unit tab-pane active" id="main">
    <h1>Welcome to 13 Favorties</h1>
    <p>Tell us if your favorite is missing.</p>
</div>
```

In your fiddle there are two problems with the code. First, you don't have quotes around "navbar navbar-inverse" and second, the links say `data-toggle="nav"` when they should say `data-toggle="tab"`

Here's a fiddle which has both the hero showing and the links working:
http://jsfiddle.net/McVRw/2/

Not related to the code but if you hadn't noticed, you have a typo in the hero: Favorties

Comment: thank you for the solution and the spelling mistake correction.